# Can't replace brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, brackets

```js
function replaceSuperscript(s) {
      var
        ix = '⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰⁱʲᵏˡᵐⁿᵒᵖʱʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻ',
        re = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
      for (var i = 0; i < ix.length; i++)
        s = s.replace(new RegExp('\\[' + re[i] + '\\]', 'g'), ix[i])
      return s
    }
    document.write(replaceSuperscript('A[1], A[t], A[0]'))
```

I tried various amount of back slashes, why this is not working, how to get it working?

Expected output: `A¹, Aᵗ, A⁰`

Comment: What's the code supposed to do?

Comment: I realized my actual problem is not replacing the string, but the fact that Node.js will note save superscript correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make use of `String.replace` callback and `Array.indexOf`

```
function replaceSuperscript(s) {
    var ix = '⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰⁱʲᵏˡᵐⁿᵒᵖʱʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻ',
        re = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    return s.replace(/\[(.)\]/g, function(m,g) {  return ix[re.indexOf(g)];  });
}
```